# Not a Function Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm facing off a classic "Not a Function" issue on Ionic Framework, I hope that you will help me to better understand this case.

I am trying to get out an object from an array. The object has private properties that I retrieve with simple getter methods.

The problem comes out when this line of the whole class above is executed:

```
this.selectedWorkoutPlan = this.workoutPlanList.find(object => object.getId() === this.id);
```

The console returns the error mentioned before.

This is my .ts file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import {WorkoutPlanService} from "../../services/workout-plan.service";
import {WorkoutPlan} from "../../models/workout-plan";

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-workout-plan-detail',
  templateUrl: 'workout-plan-detail.html',
})
export class WorkoutPlanDetailPage {

  id: number = 0;
  title: string = "";
  startDate: Date = new Date();
  endDate: Date = new Date();

  workoutPlanList: WorkoutPlan[] = [];
  selectedWorkoutPlan: WorkoutPlan = new WorkoutPlan();

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
              private workoutPlanService: WorkoutPlanService) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.id = this.navParams.get("id");
    this.workoutPlanList = this.workoutPlanService.getWorkoutPlanList();
    this.selectedWorkoutPlan = this.workoutPlanList.find(object => object.getId() === this.id);
  }

}
```

and this is the .ts model's class.

```
import {WorkoutExercise} from "./workout-exercise";

export class WorkoutPlan {

  private title: string;
  private exercises: WorkoutExercise[];
  private startDate: Date;
  private endDate: Date;
  private id: number;

  constructor() {
    this.id = new Date().getTime();
  }

  setTitle(newTitle: string) {
    this.title = newTitle;
  }

  setExercises(newExercises: WorkoutExercise[]) {
    this.exercises = newExercises;
  }

  setStartDate(newStartDate: Date) {
    this.startDate = new Date(newStartDate);
  }

  setEndDate(newEndDate: Date) {
    this.endDate = new Date(newEndDate);
  }

  setId(newId: number) {
    this.id = newId;
  }

  getTitle() {
    return this.title;
  }

  getExercises() {
    return this.exercises;
  }

  getStartDate() {
    return this.startDate;
  }

  getEndDate() {
    return this.endDate;
  }

  getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

}
```

Am I missing something in the syntax?

In my mind I thought than an array's object would have properties and methods both, isn't it?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Please, additionally provide your WorkoutPlanService.

Comment: It would also help if you'd post **exactly** what the error looks like

Comment: The error says “object.getId() is not a function”.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you might be serializing your `WorkOutPlan` objects somewhere within `WorkoutPlanService` and then parsing the strings back into `WorkOutPlan` objects, which causes you to lose the associated methods.

Are you stringifying those objects at any time?

Comment: No, I’m not stringifying any kind of objects. I use that service only to get a list of WorkoutList objects stored in the service.